# React Hook useContext: Uncaught TypeError: render2 is not a function

Tags: reactjs

While Adding the useContext in my react app. I am getting the
Please find the code snippet below.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

import AuthProvider from "./compnents/context/AuthProvider";

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  // Ensure contextValue is a function before rendering

  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: can you add the Auth provider code ?